# Add previous/next month buttons to Antd (Ant Design) calendar

Tags: reactjs, antd

It is a common pattern for calendars to have previous/next month buttons in addition to the month/year picker:

[image]

Has anybody added this to their antd calendar component? Seems like a common enough problem that I'd ask before doing it myself!

Answer (score 1):

you can add next/prev button like :

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(dayjs());
<Calendar validRange={[dayjs(props.params.startDate), dayjs(props.params.endDate)]}
         value={date}
         headerRender={() => (
           <Row justify="space-between" className="p-1">
                <Button type="link" onClick={() => setDate(dayjs())}>
                     Today
                </Button>
                <Button type="link" onClick={() => setDate(date.add(-2, 'months'))}>
                     Next Month
                </Button>
                <Button type="link" onClick={() => setDate(date.add(2, 'months'))}>
                     Previous Month
                </Button>
           </Row>
        )}
     }/>
```

you can use moment() as well